# Minimum mysql wait_timeout?

Tags: mysql, timeout, database-backup

On a hard-hit database server which ofter suffers from maximum connections being saturated, [mysqltuner.pl](http://mysqltuner.pl/mysqltuner.pl)  suggests me to  set

```
wait_timeout (< 1)
```

I am wondering whether it would be wise to follow the suggestion and set the value to a fraction of 1 or even zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should [read the manual first](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeo). It only accepts integer values starting from 1.

Not sure why mysqltuner.pl would recommend this - it's rather silly.